# Different window class name

Tags: c#, window, classname

I have a problem with a window class name, which I get by window's Win32 method - GetClassName.
My application is in .NET, C#. When I run my application for  the first time, the class name is WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.2dac507_r13_ad1. Then I close the application and my settings are saved in user.config (it's very important). When I run application for the second time, the class name is WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.338574f_r13_ad1. Then I close the application and run it again, the class name will be always the same. But when I restart my PC, the process is repeated, it means that the class name as when the application is run for the first time. Why ? Why isn't the class name the same every time I run the application?

I need it to get a window of another application. I'm trying to get it by the method FindWindow. It is true that we can use the title of the window for this method, but I need a class name, too.

It is important to mention that in case of other applications, which do not save settings, the class name is always the same, after each execution.

So, where is the problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: The problem was in selected version of .Net Framework in VS. I originally had the version 4.5.1. When I chose version 3.5, everything was fine. I really do not understand why newer versions are causing problems..